# What is the point of specifying the script type in the HTML script tag?

Tags: javascript

Why do we write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

in HTML when the script tag is understandably used just for JavaScript anyways?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's because browsers didn't default to javascript, and so was necessary.  I'm guessing it hasn't been required for quite some time (although old timers like me still add it anyway!)

Comment: "_understandably used just for JavaScript_" Except it isn't - it can be used for things other than javascript. This link has some rough info - https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/interact/scripts.html

Comment: This attribute is optional. Since Netscape 2, the default programming language in all browsers has been JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute is required and unnecessary. In HTML, it is better to leave it out. The browser knows what to do.

Comment: Here is a [list of all the supported media types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: It can be omitted for JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type

Comment: Alright, thank you.